# replace a string after specific index in javascript str.replace(from, to, indexfrom)

Tags: javascript, node.js, replace, frontend, nodes

I like to replace a string after a specific index.

ex:

```
var str = "abcedfabcdef"
    str.replace ("a","z",2)
    console.log(str) 
    abcedfzbcdef
```

Is there any way to do this in javascript or in nodeJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no direct way using the builtin `replace` function but you can always create a new function for that:

```js
String.prototype.betterReplace = function(search, replace, from) {
  if (this.length > from) {
    return this.slice(0, from) + this.slice(from).replace(search, replace);
  }
  return this;
}

var str = "abcedfabcdef"
console.log(str.betterReplace("a","z","2"))
```

Comment: @user2969187 it replaces only the first instance after the index. To replace all occurrences, something like `str.betterReplace(/a/g,"z",2)`

Comment: Just for name-sake, would prefer to call it replaceAfter :)

Comment: And to replace all, we can also use replaceAll inside the function (optionally passing a flag or naming the function so)

Answer (score 3):

Regular expression alternative, but replaces all occurrences after specific index:

```js
console.log( 'abcabcabc'.replace(/a/g, (s, i) => i > 2 ? 'z' : s) )
```